# Getting elements inside other Elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked before, but not in this way...
I have this HTML.

```
 <table class="fr ralign cartSummaryTable">
  <tr>
    <td width="320px">
      <div class="tr">
        Subtotal (5 items):
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="nowrap tr normal">$684.23
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="320px">
      <div class="tr">
        <span> Shipping to <a id="guestZipLink" href="javascript:;">19802-4358                              </a>
</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tr nowrap normal">$4.49
      </div>
    </td>
```

I want to get the second price $4.49.

My code is:

```
price= $('#cartSummaryTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) td:eq(1) .tr:eq(1)').textContent;
console.log("My price is" + price);
```

I however get undefined as my result.
What I'm I doing wrong, and what's the correct way to do it?

Comment: For a start, you have one too many td selectors in there, and you're trying to get the table by an ID, when it doesn't have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text inside that cell (i.e. $4.49):

```
var price = $("table.cartSummaryTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) div").text();
```

To get the price as a number, so you could do numeric calculations on it:

```
var price_as_float = parseFloat($("table.cartSummaryTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) div").text().substring(1));
```

Comment: Awesome @Tom works perfectly. Seen where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`$('#cartSummaryTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)')` will return jQuery object so `textContent` can't be used, You use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$('.cartSummaryTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) .tr').text();
```

OR, get underlying DOM element by usage of `get(0)` or `[0]` then `textContent` can be used.

```
$('.cartSummaryTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) .tr')[0].textContent;
```

```js
console.log($('.cartSummaryTable tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) .tr').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="fr ralign cartSummaryTable">
  <tr>
    <td width="320px">
      <div class="tr">
        Subtotal (5 items):
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="nowrap tr normal">$684.23
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="320px">
      <div class="tr">
        <span> Shipping to <a id="guestZipLink" href="javascript:;">19802-4358                              </a>
</span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="tr nowrap normal">$4.49
      </div>
    </td>
    </table>
```

Comment: After your edit - this still doesn't work - you're using an ID to get the table when it doesn't have one

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery()` returns a jQuery object, not a normal DOM node reference so you can't call `textContent` on it, but you *can* use the jQuery function `text()`.

If you did want to use `textContent`, you could use `get(0)` or `[0]`, but these are not perfectly equivalent to `text()`.

Comment: Alright @alex. just edited the text() bit, it still doesn't return $4.49